# href overrides ng-click with parameter value in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

href overrides ng-click with parameter value in **AngularJS**

**HTML:**

```
<a  href="/my-subscription" ng-click="MySubscription('<%= user._id %>')">My Subscription</a>
```

**Angular Controller code:**

```
$scope.MySubscription = function(id){
   console.log(id);
};
```

While I am redirecting my-subscription page I need to get the value but href overrides it...
Help me sort out this problem

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** Based on asker's comment:

For redirection, you should be using `$location.path(url)` in your method.

In your js:

Inject `$location` into your controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $location) {});
```

Then:

```
$scope.MySubscription = function(event, id){
    $location.path('/my-subscription');
    console.log(id);
};
```

and  in your html:

```
<a ng-click="MySubscription($event, '<%= user._id %>')">My Subscription</a>
```

Comment: i need to get value as well as redirect too

Comment: just use the `$location` injector. Remove the `href`and then use `$location.path('/my-subscription')` in your `ng-click()` function.

Comment: i did the above you said, click is not work and page also not redirecting

Comment: Try removing the `event.preventDefault()` from the method, it should work then.

Comment: `.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$location',  function($scope, $location)` Did you inject it in your controller ?

Comment: yeah i did that only, if i remove event.preventDefault() its redirecting to another page, but value not getting in console log on my-subscription page

Comment: Interchange the 2 lines, I mean `console.log` after `location.path`.

Comment: getting value but redirecting my-subscription page

Comment: while redirecting to another page, page getting refresh or reload

Comment: page not directing, but url changing **http://localhost:8000/exist-booking#/my-subscription**, i hope hashtag(#) making to not redirect

Comment: here  **localhost:8000/exist-booking#/my-subscription** my-subscription has to replace exist-booking, but here it place next to existing booking

Answer (score 0):

First off, you could use `ng-href` in place of your `href`. I know that you are not resolving (via angular) the value of your href, but it plays more nice with ng-click if you decide to add logic to that. Second your ng-click could prevent the default behavior of clicking on an achor element. To do that, you need to call .preventDefault() on the event. That you need to pass along to your method like this:

```
<a  href="/my-subscription" ng-click="MySubscription($event, '<%= user._id %>')"
>My Subscription</a>
```

.

```
$scope.MySubscription = function(event, id){
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(id);
};
```

Finally you can inline your preventDefault **instead** of passing the $event to the method like this:

```
<a  href="/my-subscription" 
ng-click="$event.preventDefault();MySubscription('<%= user._id %>')"
>My Subscription</a>
```

But then you need to remove `event` from your method again - changing it back to your original `MySubscription` method

Comment: Create a plunker or fiddle and edit your post to contain the link - that makes it easier for us to help.